# Base64 Encoding Basic Authentication Header Apache HTTP Client

Tags: java, apache, authentication, httpclient, basic-authentication

Two related questions, I'm using Apache HTTP Client 4.x API. myHttpPost is an instance of HttpPost and myHttpClient is an instance of HttpClient. I'm trying to send a request using basic authentication.  So I have a HttpClient and create a HttpPost.

The 'brute force' way of setting a basic authentication header seems to be to set it in the HttpPost header.

```
String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode("username" + ":" + "password");
myHttpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

The example above came from another stack overflow question (can't find link to it now). In relation to the Base64Encoder class - which package would I find it in or where would I download it from?

Main question - I was hoping to do basic authentication in a more aesthetic manner using the code below:

```
myHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthPolicy.BASIC),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  So is the first example above the right way to do basic authentication with Apache HTTP Client 4.0?  Or is there a cleaner/simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

> In relation to the Base64Encoder class - which package would I find it
>   in or where would I download it from?

Base64Encoder can come from various places, I couldn't find something that matches with your static `encode` method.

As for Credentials, you need to set `scheme` to `Basic` on your `AuthScope`, like so:

```
myHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "basic"),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
);
```

or

```
myHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthPolicy.BASIC),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
);
```

Comment: thanks TEG - I tried this but no success (tried the text 'basic' and the constant.). I've updated the question to reflect this additional parameter.  The base 64 encoded header does work solution works though.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old post. But, just wanted to answer so that others will benefit in future:

If you are using a username which is to be represented using Variable width encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding), then make sure that you change the encoding used to form the bytes for (username:password) as follows:
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(AuthPNames.CREDENTIAL_CHARSET, HTTP.UTF_8);

By default, the encoding used is HttpProtocolParams.HTTP_ELEMENT_CHARSET.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` does not attempt to authenticate with the origin or proxy server **unless** explicitly challenged. I suspect you would like `HttpClient` to authenticate preemptively. While the preemptive authentication is disabled per default (and I personally would discourage its application outside secure or internal networks) one can force the preemptive authentication using example below

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java

Comment: thanks for the reply oleg - have been too busy to be able to verify if it works but will get to it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out the solution suggested in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java and it works for Base64 Encoding Basic Authentication. 
I guess the

```
 // Create AuthCache instance
 AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
 // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local
 // auth cache
 BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
 authCache.put(target, basicAuth);

 // Add AuthCache to the execution context
 HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
 localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);
```

makes the miracle :)
as without this i always receive "401 Unauthorized" HTTP response

Comment: i guess typo in second word of your answer. "tired" -> "tried"